# Selecting in RecyclerView and delete from firebase in java

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I want to delete my document from firebase. But first I need to determine the document id. I tried to get document id:

```
docId = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(pos).getId();
```

Then, I just wanted to delete my document. But firebase works async so code doesnt work in 'if' statement. When we first click the button, docId variable is null or it takes the docId which was clicked before till the async code part done.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdvertisementHolder holder, int position) {
        imgUrl = publishedAdvertisements.get(position).getImgUrl();

        holder.petName.setText(publishedAdvertisements.get(position).getPetName());
        holder.petCategory.setText(publishedAdvertisements.get(position).getPetCategory());
        Picasso.get().load(publishedAdvertisements.get(position).getImgUrl()).into(holder.petImage);
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Pets").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println("bos döndü");
                            docId = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(pos).getId();
                        }
                    }
                });


                System.out.println(docId);

                if (docId != null) {
                    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                    db.collection("Pets").document(docId)
                            .delete()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                                    publishedAdvertisements.clear();
                                    getPublishedAnimals();
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                                }
                            });

                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Have you tried Sammy T solution? Does it work?

Comment: Please also note that Firebase API is asynchronous. So you might be interested in reading this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Answer (score 0):

You should structure your code so that any logic that depends on your asynchronous operation is executed or triggered within the response callback.

You can do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdvertisementHolder holder, int position) {
    imgUrl = publishedAdvertisements.get(position).getImgUrl();

    holder.petName.setText(publishedAdvertisements.get(position).getPetName());
    holder.petCategory.setText(publishedAdvertisements.get(position).getPetCategory());
    Picasso.get().load(publishedAdvertisements.get(position).getImgUrl()).into(holder.petImage);
    holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Pets").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    // The asynchronous operation has successfully completed 
                    // and returned a value to our 'onSuccess()' callback.
                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("bos döndü");
                        docId = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(pos).getId();
                        
                        System.out.println(docId);

                        // We can now use the value of docId.
                        if (docId != null) {
                            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                            db.collection("Pets").document(docId)
                                    .delete()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                                            publishedAdvertisements.clear();
                                            getPublishedAnimals();
                                            
                                            // (1)
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        
                        // I'm not sure how your RecyclerView is set up 
                        // but I'm guessing you might want to move this call
                        // to 'notifyDataSetChanged()' to the section marked (1)
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```